# Background image of an activity's layout disappears in some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, background

After lot of googling, I could not find any solution of my problem
My Problem--
              My activity's layout has an image in it's background.I can see that background image most of the time but sometimes it get disappears and only black background is visible but not my image.
What is the problem???
         Many thanks,
        Atul Bhardwaj

Comment: in which folder you put your background image ?

Comment: @ChiragRaval in drawable-ldpi as well as in drawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem---

I was calling System.gc() in my code.I think that was causing this problem(But I am not sure).
After removing System.gc(),this problem never appeared in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the image. may be this works in your case. i too had such problem and this solution worked in my case.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.This technique works sometime But  its not working in my case..any other solution?